# java interscect, union, join, distinct lists with predicate

Tags: java, list, union, predicate

Hello I have 2 lists that contains the same objects. I would like to perform any operation like intercesct, union, distinct by using predicate because I am unable to use equals to comparision.

Example:

```
class Car{
  public String id;
  public String color;
  public int hashcode(){
    //id field is used for hashcode
  }
  public boolean equals(){
    //id field is used for equals
  }
}
```

Now I have two lists of Cars. I need to find duplicates in this lists but not by id only by color.

```
List<Car> carList1 = new ArrayList(){ new Car(1,blue), new Car(2,green)};
List<Car> carList2 = new ArrayList(){ new Car(1,silver), new Car(4,green)};
```

I need to find second object from carList1 (new Car(2,green))

List Something similar to

```
Collection.intersect(carList1,carList2,comparator).
```

In C# I would use for it LINQ.

Comment: What do you mean by "predicate"? If you want to compare two objects to find if you are equal you can use the Comparator interface which returns 0 if the objects are equal. Here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: There is no library methods for this. You have to do it on your own.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793907/filtering-on-list-based-on-one-property-with-guava

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do similar think using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

1) intersect is operation on sets, not on lists. So you should construct them like

```
final Set<Car> first = ImmutableSet.of( new Car(1, "blue"), new Car(2, "green") );
```

or, if you need special comparator ( predicate mentioned )

```
final Set<Car> second = newTreeSet( new Comparator<Car>(){
    public int compare( final Car o1, final Car o2 ){
        return o1.getColor().compare( o2.getColor() );  //return 0 when predicate return true
    }
} );
second.add( new Car(1, "green")  );
```

**UPD:**  You should use only one way to construct both sets.

Than call intersection

```
 final Set<Car> intersection = Sets.intersection( first, second );
```

Comment: From the Javadoc of `Sets.intersection`: "Results are undefined if set1 and set2 are sets based on different equivalence relations (as HashSet, TreeSet, and the keySet of an IdentityHashMap all are)."

Comment: @Louis Wasserman,  I've just show two ways for constructing sets. Answer updated with clarification.

Comment: Are you sure that the TreeSet approach would work? In the Java docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) it looks like intersection relies on the contains method, which in turn relies on the equals method of the contained objects.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for this called Apache Functor Commons that supports Predicates, etc.

http://commons.apache.org/functor/

There is also Guava which one of the commenters pointed to:

http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/

You could write your own using Comparator, but to do things like intersect, join, etc its easier just to use one of these libraries.